# Helmfile - overriding values from a parent chart value using Helmfile

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile, helm3

I am trying to do simple helm config using helmfile but no success.
as mention [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#overriding-values-from-a-parent-chart) (overriding-values-from-a-parent-chart)  I would like to provide one parent configuration and override release value.
this is a release configmap

*charts/microservice-a/templates/configmap.yaml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
   labels: {{- include "microservice-a.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
   name: {{ include "microservice-a.fullname" . }}-config
   namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
   MODEL.EN: {{ .Values.model.en }}
```

*this is my helmfile.yaml*

```
releases:
   - name: microservice-a
     chart: ../charts/microservice-a
     values:
       - "./environments/{{ .Environment.Name }}/values.yaml"
```

*and this is my environments/default/values.yaml*

```
microservice-a:
  model:
    en: "model-en-1.0.mdl"
```

I found that the `{{ .Values.model.en }}`   in the configmap can not be reslove.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Helmfile is doing the equivalent of `helm install` directly; there isn't a parent-/child-chart relationship.  That means your `values.yaml` file doesn't need the top-level `microservice-a` block.

If you do want a separate configuration for each service (reasonable) then you can use `{{ .Release.Name }}` as part of the filename.  For example:

```yaml
# helmfile.yaml
releases:
   - name: microservice-a
     chart: ../charts/microservice-a
     values:
       - "./environments/{{ .Environment.Name }}/values-{{ .Release.Name }}.yaml"
```

```yaml
# environments/dev/values-microservice-a.yaml
model:
  en: "model-en-1.0.mdl"
```

Comment: I was familiar with this method (using a separate file for the release) but I thought maybe there is a way to put all release configurations in the same file, I guess not.

Comment: Having extra Helm values isn't harmful, so if only this one service uses `.Values.model` you could have a shared values file across all of your services.  You can also include both `environments/{{ .Environment.Name }}/values-common.yaml` and a per-service values file, and have Helmfile ignore the per-service file if it's not present.  Lots of options here.